# The probability that the two women will be in the same group is?

Tags: probability

> There are only two women among $20$ persons taking part in a pleasure
>   trip. The $20$ persons are divided in two groups, each group consisting
>   of $10$ persons. Then the probability that the two women will be in the
>   same group is ?

Attempt:

$n(S) = \dfrac{20!}{2!10! 10!}$

$n(E) = \dfrac{19!}{10! 9!}$ (considering the two women as one unit)

^(I am dividing 19 into groups of 9 and 10)

$P(E) = \dfrac{n(E)}{n(S)} = 1$

which is obviously wrong.

What is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have to do here is that we need to put the $2$ women in same group.

So firstly,

$n_s=$ # of ways in which 20 people can be distributed in group of 2 tens $= 20!/(10!10!2!)$

$n_e=$# of ways in which 18 people can be divide into group of 10 and 8 $= 18!/(10!8!)$

$P(E)=n_e/n_s=(18!/(10!8!))*((10!10!2!)/20!)=10*9*2/(20*19)=9/19$

If we consider the 2 women as one unit, then we in whichever group they lie we can only put 8 more people. If we consider it your way then in the case when the unit of women lie in group of 9 people(possible since we are assuming them to be one unit), then we will have 11 people in total in that group which is violation of problem statement. So instead we divide the group of 18 people into 10 and 8 and then put the women in group of 8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your n(E). Once you group them, there are only 8 other members you can choose from to fill the group women are in. There are 18 people remaining, hence it should be 8 choose 18. Once you simplify, you should get 9/19

When you do 9 choose 19, you are effectively counting cases where groups are not equal size. (i.e. if the woman pair ends up with the 10 side of the 10/9 separation, you have 11 people in one group and 9 in the other)

Another simpler approach would be this: Assign the first woman. It doesn't matter which group she is in so it has probability 1. Now the question reduces to "whats the probability that the other woman will be assigned to the same group given that woman 1 is assigned" And it's intuitive to see that there are 9 places left in the group and 19 available placement for the second woman. Hence it is 1* 9 / 19

we get the same answer with both methods, Hope it helps.

Comment: I am dividing 19 into groups of 9 and 10

Comment: yes you are but there is a chance that you will end up having unequal sizes. Consider this (i'll use 4 and 5 to avoid unnecessary typing). 4 choose 9 with one of the pairs being 2 people. 1211-11111 is one possible separation and 1111-12111 is another possible. as you see if second case happens the group sizes are not equal

Comment: consider the same question with 4 people 2 women 2 men. Men are noted x and y; woman ab. With your logic, we would group ab (lets call it k) and do divide 3 into groups of 1 and 2.  Possible gorup pairs  xk - y, yk - x , yx - k. as you see if xk-y seperation happens groups are effectively different sizes as one group has xab the other only y.